# Centering map on user location with MBXMapkit (Mapbox)

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapbox

My code to get MapKit to load on a users location upon loading worked fine until I added MapBox.

I'm initializing the `MBXRasterTileOverlay* rasterOverlay` via

```
-(void)loadMapBox{

_rasterOverlay = [[MBXRasterTileOverlay alloc] initWithMapID:@"myKey"];
_rasterOverlay.center = _mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
```

}

However I get a compiler error saying `_rasterOverlay.center` is read only. Is there any way to programmatically load the overlay at the users location and not pre-defined center of the map from MapBox studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authoritative way to do this is to pass `includeMetadata:NO` and you won't get this starting info:

https://www.mapbox.com/mbxmapkit/api/Classes/MBXRasterTileOverlay.html#//api/name/initWithMapID:includeMetadata:includeMarkers:

Comment: you are correct. I was commenting out the method this called !

Answer (score 1):

Turns out MapBox has a speical delegate that whenever annotations are added to the map, it centers on them. Commenting out the else line works

```
- (void)tileOverlay:(MBXRasterTileOverlay *)overlay didLoadMetadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata withError:(NSError *)error
{
// This delegate callback is for centering the map once the map metadata has been loaded
//
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load metadata for map ID %@ - (%@)", overlay.mapID, error?error:@"");
}
else
{
//        [_mapView mbx_setCenterCoordinate:overlay.center zoomLevel:overlay.centerZoom animated:NO];
  }
}
```